# Invoking SAS in Interactive Line Mode

Tags: sas

I’m running SAS in UNIX environment in Interactive Line Model.

And I use command "module load SAS/9.4"; "sas -nodms"
However It shows:

```
NOTE: Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by SAS Institute Inc., Cary, NC, USA. 
NOTE: SAS (r) Proprietary Software 9.4 (TS1M1) 
      Licensed to ABCDEF, Site 1234567.
NOTE: This session is executing on the Linux 2.6.32-754.14.2.el6.x86_64 (LIN 
      X64) platform.

NOTE: Updated analytical products:

      SAS/STAT 13.1
      SAS/ETS 13.1
      SAS/OR 13.1
      SAS/IML 13.1
      SAS/QC 13.1

NOTE: Additional host information:

 Linux LIN X64 2.6.32-754.14.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 14 19:35:42 UTC 2019 
      x86_64 CentOS release 6.10 (Final) 

You are running SAS 9. Some SAS 8 files will be automatically converted 
by the V9 engine; others are incompatible.  Please see 
http://support.sas.com/rnd/migration/planning/platform/64bit.html

PROC MIGRATE will preserve current SAS file attributes and is 
recommended for converting all your SAS libraries from any 
SAS 8 release to SAS 9.  For details and examples, please see
http://support.sas.com/rnd/migration/index.html


This message is contained in the SAS news file, and is presented upon
initialization.  Edit the file "news" in the "misc/base" directory to
display site-specific news and information in the program log.
The command line option "-nonews" will prevent this display.




NOTE: SAS initialization used:
      real time           1.63 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds

  1? 
  2? 
  3? 
  4?
```

I don't understand what the number 1？ 2？ means.

Comment: Pretty sure those are just log numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are the prompts for you to enter your SAS code. You must have entered three empty lines for it show 1 to 4.

When you are done you can use the endsas; command to exit from SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure those are just the log numbers and the error itself tells you how to suppress that output: `command line option -nonews`

You're basically starting SAS with that command, not actually calling your program. When SAS starts this is the code that would appear in the log.